# Understanding architecture and folder structure in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony

I'm completely new to Symfony 2 and i can't really understand the folder structure and organization of a project. I know what a **bundle** is, but what is unclear to me is:

- what's the **main directory** (the directory to be copied on the web server for deployment)
- where **assets** (css, javascript) should be placed
- if (and how) environment should be changed when publishing my website

I've already read the book on Symfony website and i can't find those answers.

Answer (score 4):

- The web root of a Symfony2 app is the 'web' directory, but when you push to production the entire symfony2 project should be pushed not just the web root.

From the [symfony2](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/page_creation.html) book

> app/: This directory contains the application configuration;
>   src/: All the project PHP code is stored under this directory;
>   vendor/: Any vendor libraries are placed here by convention;
>   web/: This is the web root directory and contains any publicly accessible files;

- The assets should be kept in the bundles 'Resources/public/[css/js/images]' folders. From here you would have to copy or symlink those directories into the web root to make them accessible. Symfony2 comes with a command line utility located in the 'app' directory. `app/console assets:install web --symlink` command executed from the command line of your symfony2 project root will install all of the bundle's assets for you.
- To change environments and you are using Apache you would use a .htaccess file and mod_rewrite to select which environment you would want to use

  ```
  RewriteEngine On 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app.php [QSA,L]
  ```

  using `/app.php` puts me into production mode and using `/app_dev.php` would put me in    development mode.

Answer (score 1):

- The main directory  contains the app folder.
- The assets should be
  placed in the bundles folder they're related to. This folder is named
  "public".
- Read [this](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/configuration/environments.html#executing-an-application-in-different-environments). All you need to do is remove the app_dev.php file.