# Symfony project structure - why src/ and app/?

Tags: symfony

According to [best practices](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/creating-the-project.html) for Symfony 3 projects, there should be:

> - `app/config/`, stores all the configuration defined for any environment;
> - `app/Resources/`, stores all the templates and the translation files for the application;
> - `src/AppBundle/`, stores the Symfony specific code (controllers and routes), your domain code (e.g. Doctrine classes) and all your business logic;
> - `var/` ...
> - `tests/AppBundle/`, stores the automatic tests (e.g. Unit tests) of the application.
> - `vendor/`, this is the directory where Composer installs the application's dependencies and you should never modify any of its contents;
> - `web/`, stores all the front controller files and all the web assets, such as stylesheets, JavaScript files and images.

The purpose of `bin`, `var`, `vendor`, and `web` directories is obvious, but I'm wondering, why to separate `app`, `src`, and `tests`.

As I understand it, `src` contains bundles which make the application. Therefore I would expect them to be in the `app` directory. Also , the `tests` directory is complete mystery as it should be in the bundle - `src/AppBundle/Tests`. From other side, why are templates (`app/Resource/`) outside the AppBundle?

I found some notes about sharing bundles between applications, but since we have Composer, such Bundles are in the `vendor` directory and they have separate repositories. However, I understand it may be useful to have multiple bundles in the application without need for additional infrastructure, but then `src` is completely misleading name.

So, what is motivation behind this directory structure? Or is it just historical heritage?

Unless there is a good reason not to, I guess I will remove duplicate directories like `tests/AppBundle` and `app/Resources` as they are also in the `AppBundle`.

Comment: Some interesting reads : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23993295/what-is-the-new-symfony-3-directory-structure http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625960/understanding-architecture-and-folder-structure-in-symfony2 http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_architecture.html . For what I understand, `app` is there for the configuration, and `tests` to be abble for phpunit to run from the project root without having to explicitly specify the path of the configuration file.

Comment: To run phpunit I would expect some unified entry point, like `bin/command tests:run`, rather than relying on default configuration of an arbitrary tool (what if I use something else/more to run tests?).

Comment: I don't know how to respond to your question... Anyway, 2 more interesting threads about the directory architecture : https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/12991 & https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/issues/584 : `app` for config & templates, `src` for PHP source code.

Comment: Personally I would keep the src/AppBundle and move the app stuff to it.  src seems more of a standard. http://blog.nikolaposa.in.rs/2017/01/16/on-structuring-php-projects/ The directory structure was refined from S2 to S3.  Would not be surprised to see more changes for S4.

Comment: Thank you, the https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/issues/584 is actually quite useful for understanding. As I see it now, the `app/Resources` and `tests/` are redundant and everything should be in `src/`, except few things that don't fit bundles.

Comment: Feel free to use the project structure you want !  But don't complain if someone after you doesn't understand what you did because you didn't use the standard one. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So thanks to the links provided in the comments, it looks like `app/Resources` and `tests/` directories are just a historical heritage. Since everything in Symfony is a bundle, these directories are also in the AppBundle, so I can drop the duplicates. The `app/` is here just to bootstrap the AppBundle and contain stuff not fitting any bundle.

Comment: also you can override there some reusable bundles elements like templates for fos user bundle for example

Answer (score 1):

To Asset like bootstrap is better to use web/

http://symfony.com/doc/master/best_practices/web-assets.html

**Store your assets in the web/ directory.**